# Trouble using NSThread and core data, changes are not written correctly

Tags: ios, core-data

I am having a problem i simply just can't figure out the solution to.

My app configured to use Core Data(with the templatecode in AppDelegate created by xCode), imports a lot of data in a background thread. The issue is that all the changes i make to Core Data in the UI thread, isn't saved to store(sometimes) if i have run the large import. All the data is saved correctly if i doesn't run the import, and the problem is not consistent, it is a on/off issue, but i have tracked it down to be the import that is causing the problems.

My thread code looks like this (simplified)

```
-(void)startSynchronization{
self.thread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(startSync:) object:nil];
[self.thread start];
}


-(void)startSync{
NSManagedObjectContext *importContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];  
[importContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator:self.persistentStoreCoordinator];
[importContext setUndoManager:nil];
... import a lot of code and create thousands of core data entities..

}
```

The persistentStoreCoordinator(PSC from now on) is the PSC from the app's AppDelegate, and I think this is the issue. I read the multiple threads should use seperate PSC's, but how do i create a PSC and assign it with the Core Data file that is created in the AppDelegate template code ?

The reading of the Core Data after the import is working just fine, but when i later on tag one of my "Document" entity's in the Core Data model as my favourite, this change is not written to the database even though i call save on my context from AppDelegate.

I thought that the global PSC was used to sync multiple contexts, one context in my app, and the import context in the thread import code ?

How can i make sure that the import code and the UI code sees the same changes, and that my store is consistent ?

Thank you

/Jacob

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They revamped the way multithreading worked in iOS 5/MacOS 10.7. Now, there are three modes for multithreading Core Data: `NSConfinementConcurrencyType`, `NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType` and `NSMainQueueConcurrencyType`. The first one is the way things worked in the past, and it's the one you're using. I mention the others because they might be worth looking into, and because the terminology might be useful when searching.

For the thread-confinement method, you create a new managed object context per thread, as you're doing. I take it that after your loop you're calling `save` on the background context. The step you're missing is responding to the `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`. From Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/coredata/Articles/cdConcurrency.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003385-SW1):

> Typically, on thread A you register for the managed object context save notification, `NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification`. When you receive the notification, its user info dictionary contains arrays with the managed objects that were inserted, deleted, and updated on thread B. Because the managed objects are associated with a different thread, however, you should not access them directly. Instead, you pass the notification as an argument to `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` (which you send to the context on thread A). Using this method, the context is able to safely merge the changes.

To sum up, what you do is subscribe to that notification, and when it happens (and your selector is called) you just call `mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:` on your main thread's managed object context, passing the notification object to the latter method, like so:

```
- (void)mergeChanges:(NSNotification *)notification 
{
    if (notification.object != self.context) {
        [self.context mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:notification];
    }

    return;
}
```

Assume that you've already subscribed to the notification, and that `self.context` refers to your main thread's managed object context. That should handle getting the updates across.

The reason I mentioned the other concurrency types above is that another method for doing concurrency (if you're using the latest OS) involves parent and child contexts. You could have a context operating in private queue mode, and set its parent to be your main MOC. When a context has a parent, a save operation on the child context just pushes its changes to the parent, without touching the disk. That might be an alternative pattern that you could look into.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I actually read some time ago about the ContectDidSaveNotification, but i forgot all about it, and maybe i didn't quite understand it at the time :( Stupid me.. I have not implementet the merge pattern, and all seems to be well now :)

Comment: @JacobRungwald you should make Amy's question right (the tick box beside her answer) if this is the correct answer. Then you both get reputation points.